# Wrap Commerce widget attributes

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

[image]

Clicking on Whislist, it adds product to wishlist, and hides the wishlist button and replace it with text 'Already in wishlist' which I need to style and position, so to do that I at least need it to be in a div.

Is there a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video should sort you out. You need to use the hook form alter
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYMd6WDqxKY